# How to Notify A DateTime Change Event in the WPF Data Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, binding, colors

I have a WPF APP which use binding like this

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="BeginDate" Binding="{Binding BeginDate}">
   <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BeginDate, Converter={StaticResource beginDate} }" />
       </Style>
   </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

And The Converter is as below

```
public class ColorBeginDateConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (value == null) return Brushes.Transparent;

            DateTime dateTime = ConvertBackToDateTime(value.ToString()); //Convert Back To DateTime using a private function

            var compare = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, dateTime); //Compare the time
            if (compare > 0) return Brushes.Orange; else return Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Brushes.Transparent;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "not implemented";
    }
```

The question is how do I observe the DateTime change of everday?   I need this color converter to dynamic change it's color by its self but when  the DateTime.Now changed, the color won't be notified to change.

Best regards.
And many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Background color depends of changing DateTime.Now, but in your code you bind to BeginDate that will remain unchanged. So you have to send notification that BeginDate was changed explicitly, by triggering PropertyChanged event in your ViewModel. You may use timer for this:

```
        DispatcherTimer _timer = null;
```

...

```
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged("BeginDate");
        _timer.Start();
```

...

```
        // Do no forget to stop timer when VM is no longer needed to prevent memory leak
        _timer.Stop();
```

**UPDATE**

Following sample is a proof of a concept for the solution with timer. Background of cells with BeginDate will change it's color from Orange to Transparent once per second. EmployeesListViewModel is a DataContext for a control with DataGrid. Do not forget to call StopTimer() for each EmployeeDetailsViewModel to prevent memory leaks.

XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ColorBeginDateConverter x:Key="beginDate" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>      
    <DataGrid Name="gridEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="BeginDate" Binding="{Binding BeginDate}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BeginDate, Converter={StaticResource beginDate} }" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public class EmployeesListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetailsViewModel> _employees;

    public EmployeesListViewModel()
    {
        _employees = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetailsViewModel>();

        _employees.Add(new EmployeeDetailsViewModel() { BeginDate = DateTime.Now });
        _employees.Add(new EmployeeDetailsViewModel() { BeginDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetailsViewModel> Employees
    {
        get { return _employees; }
    }   
}


public class EmployeeDetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DispatcherTimer _timer = null;

    public EmployeeDetailsViewModel()
    {

        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) => { OnPropertyChanged("BeginDate"); };
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void StopTimer()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    private DateTime _beginDate;
    public DateTime BeginDate
    {
        get { return _beginDate; }
        set
        {
            _beginDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BeginDate");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class ColorBeginDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0)
                return Brushes.Transparent;
            else
                return Brushes.Orange;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Brushes.Transparent;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
    object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return "not implemented";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to tell how this works.   BeginDate is a trigger for the DateTime.Now, which means when BeginDate  small than DateTime.Now then it means this trigger begins, so the background color in this datagrid has to be changed into Orange.  I tries your method, when the DateTime.Now changed, the color won't change. Do I need to use DateTime.Now as  OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: The main problem is that you are binding to BeginDate, and it does not change after that, but to change background you need to refresh your binding. Using DateTime.Now in OnPropertyChanged will not help. Why approach with timer didn't work for you? Could you please put a breakpoint to your Convert method just to be sure that your binding to BeginDate is properly updated once per second?